# Specify millisecond-speed of an infinite loop

Tags: haskell, concurrency

My main function has one infinite loop and I'd like to execute each loop of it every 100 millisecond. I know it's done by some concurrent or parallel method, but I've never done such things before and have no idea even where to start from. How would you implement such function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your loop body takes negligible time, just use `threadDelay` from `Control.Concurrent`:

```
import Control.Concurrent

main = forever $ do
  mainBody
  threadDelay (100*1000) -- value in microseconds
```

Update: To account for the time of your loop body, use this:

```
import Data.Time.Clock
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

mainBody :: IO ()
mainBody = putStrLn "hi"

main = forever $ do
  start <- getCurrentTime
  mainBody
  end <- getCurrentTime
  let diff = diffUTCTime end start
      usecs = floor (toRational diff * 1000000) :: Int
      delay = 100*1000 - usecs
  if delay > 0
    then threadDelay delay
    else return ()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the loop body takes different time. One could take 80 milliseconds, and another might take 0 at all. I'd like to match up all their time length equally.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell's threads are light-weight, so a quick solution would be to fork on each cycle. Thus you'll end up using the main thread as a manager of worker threads, which ensures that a worker gets spawned every 100 micros.

```
import Control.Concurrent

main = 
  forever $ do
    forkIO $ loopCycle
    threadDelay $ 100 * 10^3
```

In case you care about exceptions not getting lost and getting reraised in the main thread instead, I recommend taking a look at [the "slave-thread" package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/slave-thread). Actually, I'd recommend to use that package instead of `forkIO` and brothers by default, but then I'm the author so I might be subjective.

Also note that the above solution might cause an accumulation of worker threads in case the `loopCycle` will take longer than 100 micros to execute too often. To protect against such a scenario, you can implement a strategy in the manager thread, which will ensure that the number of active workers is limited. Following is how such a strategy could be implemented:

```
-- From the "SafeSemaphore" package
import qualified Control.Concurrent.SSem as Sem

main =
  manager 12 (100 * 10^3) $ putStrLn "Implement me!"

manager :: Int -> Int -> IO () -> IO ()
manager limit delay worker =
  do
    sem <- Sem.new limit
    forever $ do
      forkIO $ Sem.withSem sem $ worker
      threadDelay delay
```

Comment: I will check out the library. Thank you for your idea!

Comment: "implement a strategy in the manager thread, which will ensure that the number of active workers is limited" how? using which functions? some  pointers would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

You could use sleep to pause the loop at the end of every iteration for 100 milliseconds. https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=sleep

Comment: But note the warning: _Warning: This function has several shortcomings ..._ It's better to use `threadDelay` from Control.Concurrent.

Comment: @user5402 care to expand?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Good observation, I didn't think of this, although I am not any expert with Haskell @user5402